# ¿Como lograr que un botón elimine exactamente al usuario que esta en su fila?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, mysqli

Estoy realizando un index para un perfil de administrador, donde deberia ser capaz de actualizar o eliminar, en pocas palabras, aplicar una `sentencia SQL` usando los datos a su izquierda.

Así luce.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta pantalla se va a ver reflejado la cantidad de usuarios total registrados, ahora, yo estoy haciendo esto con un `while` por lo que no encuentro la forma de que cada uno tenga una ID diferente para poder manipular esos datos en especifico con los botones.

A continuación el código:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'conexion.php';

//creas una variable con el contenido base de la tabla

$tabla = "
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Nombre </th>
            <th>Fecha creacion </th>
            <th>Nick </th>
            <th>Telefono </th>
            <th>Actualizar</th>
            <th>Eliminar</th>
    </thead>
      ";

//pregunta primero que tipo de usuario es 
if ($_SESSION['cargo'] == "lector") {
  //como es un lector necesitaras el id
  $id_sesion = $_SESSION['id'];
  //ejecutas la sentencia sql
  $consulta = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE id = '". $id_sesion . "'" );
  //preguntas si trajo resultados
  if ( $consulta->num_rows > 0)
  {


    //rescorres los resultados que haya traido
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta) )
    {
      //como ya tenemos la base de la tabla aqui le sumamos las filas
      $tabla.= "</tr>";
      $tabla.= " <td>".$row['nombre']."</td>";
      $tabla.= " <td>".$row['fecha_creacion']."</td>";
      $tabla.= " <td>".$row['nick']."</td>";
      $tabla.= " <td>".$row['telefono']."</td>";
      $tabla.= "</tr>";
    }
  }

}
else if ($_SESSION['cargo'] == 'admin'){
  //como es un aministrador no necesitamos id
  $consulta2 = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM Usuario" );
  //preguntamos si trae registros
  if($consulta2->num_rows > 0){

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta2))
      {
        //sumamos las filas que trae
        $tabla.= "</tr>";
        $tabla.= " <td id='nom'>".$row['nombre']."</td>";
        $tabla.= " <td>".$row['fecha_creacion']."</td>";
        $tabla.= " <td>".$row['nick']."</td>";
        $tabla.= " <td>".$row['telefono']."</td>";
        $tabla.= " <td><button id='update_admin' class='update2'>Actualizar</button></td>";
        $tabla.= " <td><button id='update_admin' class='delete2'>Eliminar</button></td>";
        $tabla.= "</tr>";

      }
  }
}

//aqui cierras la tabla
$tabla.= "</table>";
//la imprimes
echo $tabla;

header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
```

Use este código, pero claramente, termino con todos los datos en la columna nombre con el mismo ID... Planeo usar `Javascript/ajax` para manejar la update/delete.

```
$tabla.= " <td id='nom'>".$row['nombre']."</td>";
```

Comment: @srJJ Enfrentando un dilema aquí, ¿Alguna idea de como manejar este caso? No se si existe una función o algo que me estoy perdiendo.

Comment: debes guardar el id en el boton

Comment: El id diferente tendría q ser el Identificador unico que tienen en la base, de ahi lo traes, y en el boton le asignas ese id. Tambien vas a tener q usar una funcion que borra o edite usuarios dependiendo de el id q le llegue por parametro. Esa funcion la llamas desde el boton. Mas o menos es la idea.

Comment: Si vas a hacerlo por ajax entonces ponle el id de usuario al botón. Entonces en el evento onclick(e) envías el parámetro e.id por ajax y lo eliminas desde php.
Por otro lado no es recomendable poner dos elementos con el mismo id en una página.

Comment: Dame un momento te genero como deberia ser

Comment: El botón actualizar y eliminar tienen la misma id... Igual si cambias el nombre, con cada bucle se duplicarán las id.

Comment: @AndySamuel  hice  edite la linea de codigo del boton en  `$tabla.= " <td><button id=' ".$row['id']."' class='update2'>Actualizar</button></td>";` y efectivamente ahora cada ID de cada boton es igual al de la fila que pertenece, no se de que nombre hablas que cambia con el bucle.

Comment: Podrias mas hablar mas al respecto de tomar el parametro e.id ?

Hasta ahora para seleccionar, las veces que he usado ajax, solamente debo cambiar el segundo parametro por el  ID de la etiqueta que quiero tomar, no he usado tal cosas como  `onclick(e) e.id `  y no se bien a que te refieres, disculpa.

 `$(document).on('click', '#delete-btn'`

Comment: Si, es verdad, solo que desde ajax o php se puede validar cual de los dos fue presionado, pero voy mojorar la respuesta de acuerdo a tu recomendacion

Comment: Lo decía por el código que tienes en la pregunta, los dos botones tienen el id #update_admin

Comment: Oh, ya, entiendo, entiendo, un error mio, si, gracias por hacermelo notar @AndySamuel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria asi Bro, mira en cada vuelta de bucle le poner el `id` del registro al id del `button`, asi:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta2))
{
  //sumamos las filas que trae
  $tabla.= "</tr>";
  $tabla.= " <td id='nom'>".$row['nombre']."</td>";
  $tabla.= " <td>".$row['fecha_creacion']."</td>";
  $tabla.= " <td>".$row['nick']."</td>";
  $tabla.= " <td>".$row['telefono']."</td>";
  $tabla.= " <td><button id='edit".$row['id']."' class='update2'>Actualizar</button></td>";
  $tabla.= " <td><button id='delete".$row['id']."' class='delete2'>Eliminar</button></td>";
  $tabla.= "</tr>";

}
```

**ACTUALIZACION**  de modifico el nombre del id, para que los dos botones sean diferentes entre si y asi se asegura la recomendacion de los ids sean diferentes

espero te sirva, me cuentas como te fue...

Comment: Tras darle un par de vueltas al primer comentario que me mandaste, termine en la misma conclusión, efectivamente así es como me quedo y ahora el id de cada botón es diferente y corresponde al de su respectiva fila.

Comment: Excelente bro, asi es, aqui hice una modificacion para que los botones sean id diferentes, ahora en el evento onclick, ya caprutas el id del boton y con eso ya puedes validar que usuario vas a eliminar quitandole las primeras letras, espero me haga entender

Answer (score 1):

Proba asignándole un evento al Button, el evento onclick levantaría una función en javaScript la cual esperara un numero como parámetro el cual sera tu id.

onclick="mifuncion(id)"

Revisa esto:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40134185/9865025

Comment: Para que sea mejor recibida tu respuesta lee [answer] lee los consejos y edita la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar hacer esto. Ya que usaras Javascript/Ajax

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta2)) {
 $tabla.= "</tr>";
 $tabla.= " <td id='nom'>".$row['nombre']."</td>";
 $tabla.= " <td>".$row['fecha_creacion']."</td>";
 $tabla.= " <td>".$row['nick']."</td>";
 $tabla.= " <td>".$row['telefono']."</td>";
 $tabla.= " <td><button OnClick='UpdateU(".$row['id'].")' class='update2'>Actualizar</button></td>";
 $tabla.= " <td><button OnClick='DeleteU(".$row['id'].")'  class='delete2'>Eliminar</button></td>";
 $tabla.= "</tr>";
}
```

Luego con JS/Ajax y jQuery

```
function DeleteU(codigo) {
  parametros = {                  
    "prmCodigo":codigo
             }
  $.ajax({
        data:parametros,url:'Procesar.php?op=Delete',type:'POST',
        beforeSend:function(){},
        success:function(respuesta){
            if(respuesta == 1) {
            console.log("Se elimino correctamente =)");
            } else {
            console.log("Error =( ");
            }
        }    
       });            
}
```

En Procesar.php..

```
<?php

switch ($_REQUEST["op"]){

case 'Delete':
  $codigo= $_POST['prmCodigo'];
  $sentencia ="DELETE ......... WHERE CODIGO = '$codigo'";
  $res = mysqli_query($conexion, $sentencia);
  if($res) { 
  echo 1; 
  } else { 
  echo 0; 
  }
break;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

te dejo una solucion es por javascript y  jquery

**el javascript**:

```
**$(document).ready(function profesores(){
    $("#addProfesores").click(function(){
        var nuevaFila="<tr> <td><input type='num' name='cuitProfesores' placeholder='Cuit'></td> \ <td><input type='text' name='nombreProfesores' placeholder='Nombre'></td> \ <td><input type='text' name='apellidoProfesores' placeholder='Apellido'></td> \ <td><input type='email' name='emailProfesores' placeholder='Email'></td> \ <td><input type='text' name='ComisionProfesores' placeholder='Comision'></td> \ <td><input type='button' class='del' value='Eliminar Fila'></td></tr>";
        $("#tablaProfesores tbody").append(nuevaFila);
    });
    // evento para eliminar la fila
    $("#tablaProfesores").on("click", ".del", function profesores(){
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();**
```

**el html:**

**`

```
            <br>
            <tr>
                <th>Cuit</th>

                <th>Nombre</th>

                <th>Apellidos</th>

                <th>Email</th>

                <th>Comision</th>

                <th><input type="button" id="addProfesores" value="Añadir Fila"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="profesores">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="num" name='cuitProfesores' placeholder='Cuit'></td>
                <td><input type="text" name='nombreProfesores' placeholder='Nombre'></td>
                <td><input type="text" name='apellidoProfesores' placeholder='Apellido'></td>
                <td><input type="email" name='emailProfesores' placeholder='Email'></td>
                <td><input type="num" name='ComisionProfesores' placeholder='Comision'></td>
                <td><input type='button' class='del' value='Eliminar Fila'></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>`**
```